# SSRS hide/show logic breaks in preview when running on server

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, reportbuilder3.0, ssrs-2014

I am running into an issue where I have multiple overlapping text boxes that all have hide / show logic applied to them. The logic is designed so that no more than one text box is showing at a time. In Report Builder 3.0, the report looks just fine. However when I upload it to a report server, the preview that is displayed after running the report does not take my logic into consideration for certain values. Some of the time it looks just fine, but some of the time multiple text boxes will display in the preview and look terrible, but when I export to PDF, the end result is as I would expect - no issues; the text boxes that should be hidden are hidden. I have tried IE and Chrome, and both have the same display issue. I have also posted this multiple SSRS servers - one is running 2008 and the other is 2014.

Comment: Try putting the text boxes in rectangles and using the visibility of the rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

Why couldn't you use one textbox and apply logic on the data instead? SSRS does funny things when report controls overlap each other exported to different formats.